# The bean defaultKafkaStreamsConfig defined in class path resource could not be registered

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkastreamconfig() {
        
         HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
         props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-stream1");
         props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
         props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
         props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
         
         return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
        
    }

}
```

The application throws below exception while loading

```
The bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsConfig', defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]
could not be registered.

A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource
[com/kafka/kafkastreams/config/KafkaStreamConfig.class]
and overriding is disabled.
```

**Action:**
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`

Any help would be great

Comment: enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true   setting is not working

Comment: Please take the time to format your question properly, so that it's clear what's code / error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded the java version from version 8 to 12 and its working.

The Annotation: @ConditionalOnMissingBean and @AutoConfigureBefore are not working.